# Regex which allow minus (-) sign only

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, validation, decimal

I am using this regex to validate input strings as `decimal` values in Textbox.

`^\d{1,16}((\.\d{1,4})|(\.))?$`

Now I want to allow `negative decimal` values. I have found many similar questions on SO. And I tried something like these:

`/^-?`, `(\+|-)?`, `\.\d{1,4}\-` but not working.

The reason I asked a new question here because I am using Textbox `TextChanged` event and I need to check each character entered into the Textbox.

> So the first character, minus(-) sign, should be valid

### Valid Values:

**Positive Values**

- `1`
- `1.`
- `1.1`
- `1.1111`

**Negative Values**

- `-`
- `-1`
- `-1.`
- `-1.1`
- `-1.1111`

The Regex that I have above validate for positive values. How can I modify my Regex to allow negative values? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does it absolutely *have* to be a regex? Wouldn't [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ew0seb73.aspx) be more appropriate in this case? What about cultures where the decimal separator is a comma instead of a dot? What about thousands seperator?

Comment: @Corak Thanks for your time and help, much appreciated. I agree with you about culture-specific formats. Since I have been using `TextChanged` event in this case, when Decimal.TryParse() is trying to convert minus(-) sign which will go in as string representation for the first time, a return value will be failed. How can I handle that?

Comment: The question is, why are you validating in the `TextChanged` event and not in the `Validating` event (which would not be called on every press of a key)?

Comment: I have a panel to display the calculation. E.g. Current balance - 500, Adjustment Value - 20 (This value is entered in the textbox where I validate the input strings). So new balance is updated according to the values entered by the user. When a user enter `2` for the first time, new balance is 498. `20` then `480`. That's why I have to use `TextChanged` event in my form. Anyway, I appreciate your help. Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to escape the minus sign because `-` is a special character.

Try `(\+|\-)?` (note the backslash).

*Edit:* Not sure if this will do what you want, but it's a lot simpler:

`^\-?\d*\.?\d*$`

Will match any decimal (1 to infinite chars on either side of a decimal, with or without a -).
More details here: http://regex101.com/r/rP7cG2

Comment: It's only a special character inside a character class (`[A-Z]`), I don't think it has to be escaped elsewhere, does it?

Comment: Funny, I'm actually not totally sure on that. That said, you might find the edited string significantly simpler?

Comment: @r3mus Thanks for your help. It will work for any positive and negative decimal values but it will not match for minus(-) sign only.

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't see that edit. Fixed. (Changed + to * on first decimal)

Comment: @Jowie - what decimal value is `-`?

Comment: @Corak Like I mentioned in my question, I am using textbox 'TextChanged' event. So, the regex must validate each character. For e.g. if a user want to key in -1.2, the regex will validate for 4 times, `-`, `-1`, `-1.` and `-1.2`.